# How to close React.js PWA to apply updates?

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

We are developing a React.js PWA.Is it possible to programmatically close application after gets update to apply them?And how?Is there another solution for it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not close the application, you are not allowed to close the tab opened by the user.  Only tabs that have been opened with a code can be closed with a code.
This is your problem with killing Application in RAM(app cleaner).
This will clear the cache of the previous version of the application and replace it with the new **main.chunk.js**.

I have a solution that you can update the program without closing it, for doing this you can use the [**"clear-cache"**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clear-cache) React library.

Answer (score 0):

> close application after gets update to apply them

This in case of a web application would be killing the caches and refreshing the browser tab.

You can kill caches by applying something like versoning/time stamps/unique id etc to the resource URLs, so that on refresh browser detects them as a new resource that needs to be downloaded.

You can force refresh the app using [`location.reload();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

Comment: Thanks bro.I will try it and i will comment here.